# SwiftUI Error when playing video when view appears

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video

I have a basic video player that presents videos from a url. When the view appears I call `player.play()` and in doing so I think it causes the error below. I think I have to wait until the video is fully fetched from the url to try and play it. How can I achieve this?

> Main thread blocked by synchronous property query on not-yet-loaded property (PreferredTransform) for HTTP(S) asset. This could have been a problem if this asset were being read from a slow network.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct MainVideoPlayer: View {
   let url: URL
   @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
   
   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           VideoPlayer(player: $player)
       }
        .onAppear {
           player = AVPlayer(url: url)
           self.player.play()
        }
   }
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   @Binding var player : AVPlayer
   
   func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

       let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
       controller.player = player
       controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
       controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       return controller
   }
   
   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to execute `player.play` inside a `Task`? I read the document that before iOS 16 it should have been invoked on MainThread, maybe they've changed.

Comment: @son I tried using the task and it didn't work. Is there a way to add a status observer to the player. Maybe an observer can notify me when the video is ready to play.

Comment: There were assets pre-loader before. I think it's `AVAsset(url: URL).load` now.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a different (more modern) approach, using Apple `VideoPlayer`, such as in this example code:

Works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (and Previews), macCatalyst and MacOS.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
 
 
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainVideoPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")!)
    }
}

struct MainVideoPlayer: View {
    let url: URL
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .frame(height: 300)
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
            }
            .onAppear {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                player.play()
            }
    }
}
```

See also: [VideoPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer)

Comment: I ran your code on an empty project and it gave the same error that the original posted talked about

Comment: My code works well for me, tested on MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. **However** the video url has changed,
it is now `https://sample-videos.com/video321/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4`.
 Replace the old url with the new one, and let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: The question is not whether or not it works, but that it prints errors on the console that the original poster mentioned about. I ran your code on an empty project and it still prints the errors.

Comment: All works well for me, I do not get any errors with or without the correct url.
 I tested my answer on MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, also tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. You of course need to ensure that the App sandbox is set with Network Outgoing connections. What system are you using/targeting?
 What kind of empty project did you setup? Do you have a slow network, as the error mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Can't use `@State` or `@Binding` with classes. That `AVPlayer`needs to go inside your `AVPlayerViewController`.  You need a `let url` and you can use `updateUIViewController` to start playing if the url is different from last time the representable was init, e.g. something like:

```
let url: URL

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { 

    if uiViewController.player.url != url {
        uiViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok In my case I have the player declared inside the view because I want to access it in order to play/pause mute/unmute via buttons from the swift ui view. If I put the AVPlayer inside the AVPlayerViewController then how can I access it from the view.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem too since I still try and play the video directly when the view appears. Would you know how to add an observer to check when the video is loading and then when the video is ready to play?

Comment: access it in `updateUIViewController` like I showed